# opencv imutils resize videostream

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, imutils

I have a code that will resize the videostream using imutils

```
vStream = VideoStream(src=args["webcam"]).start()
frme = vStream.read()
frme = imutils.resize(frme, width=280)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frme, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

However it is maintaining the aspect ratio and because of that the face will become smaller and I may not be able to perform some videostream processing because I need the face to become closer to the camera.

Is there a way where size of the videostream has the width of 280 at the same time the face is closer to camera? .... zoom ? Crop?

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/CJoseFlores/python-OpenCV-Zoom is code that uses `imutils.resize()` and *cropping* for zoom in a videostream ( grabbing frame from stream -> zooming -> display zoomed frames as stream ). Alternatively you can use `cv.INTER_LINEAR()` ( *linear interpolation* ) for zooming